# Game arena or gaming arena or gamer arena?

Tags: word-choice

I am going to present a proposal to build a gaming arena for my English class.

I couldn't find any proper answer online.

Many websites use *gaming arena*, some of them use *game arena* or *gamer arena*.

> As a gamer myself, I believe a **gaming** arena will allow students to practise their
>   gameplay.

OR

> As a gamer myself, I believe a **game** arena will allow students to practise their
>   gameplay.

OR

> As a gamer myself, I believe a **gamer** arena will allow students to practise their
>   gameplay.

Any idea which word is more suitable?

Comment: It depends on what is idiomatic in your locality and what is idiomatic for the type of "sport" that will be practiced.

Comment: Is the arena to be a space (either physical or virtual) where gamers compete against each other, or is it to be a space where games can be played by a number of gamers but not, necessarily, involving the other gamers using the same space? Any answer I give might be influenced by your response to this comment.

Comment: @BoldBen The arena is used for eSport competition that may located at a shopping mall or stadium for gamers to compete against each other.

Comment: In that case I would prefer _game arena_  by analogy with conventional sports arenas such as _boxing arena, football arena_ and so on. As most sports are also referred to as _games_ the term _gaming arena_ might be a bit clearer. I don't believe that _gamer arena_ is correct, again by analogy with conventional sports, I can't imagine a _boxer arena_ or _footballer arena_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with any of these constructions. It remains to determine which phrase is the most idiomatic, which occurs most often in English as she is spoken or written. For this question, I defer to Google [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gaming%20arena%2C%20game%20arena%2C%20gamer%20arena&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgaming%20arena%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgame%20arena%3B%2Cc0) which reveals that *game arena* occurs most commonly, *gaming arena* with about half the frequency, and *gamer arena* almost never.